# android.widget.textview is deprecated

Tags: android, textview

I am writing Java code for an Android activity. I am facing the following warning message:

> android.widget.textview is deprecated

However, I couldn't get an alternative widget to use.

```
final TextView prince = findViewById(R.id.Principle_Result);
```

TextView has a crossover. It does ask to import org.w3c.dom.Text; Not sure about the correct way. Please help, thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R5VN.png)

Gradle as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ssa.emisecond"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Import

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: `android.widget.TextView` is not deprecated. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView).

Comment: @try to post ur full code with import and build.gradle

Comment: @CommonsWare Hello, I am getting the message though it's not deprecated - please refer the image.

Comment: Perhaps you are not importing `android.widget.TextView`, but instead are importing something else named `TextView` that happens to be deprecated. Or, perhaps there is something seriously wrong with your IDE. For example, perhaps you changed the text formatting rules such that all classes show a strikethrough.

Comment: I have added gradle and import. I have imported TextView. I am getting similar message with String as well